# Why have I no callback query when i use URL in inline_keyboard?

Tags: bots, webhooks, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

Why  have I no callback query when I use URL in inline_keyboard
in telegram bot?

```
$keyboard = ['inline_keyboard'=>[[['text'=>'test','callback_data'=>'1', 'url'=>'https://t.me/']]]];
```

Comment: An answer with reasoning: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47553762/3050249

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use both callback_data and url together. Only one of them will work.