# Telegram callback_data for link buttons

Tags: node.js, callback, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm sending a link button throught a Telegram bot and I would like to get the callback_data after the user opens the url.

My options are:

```
var options = {
          parse_mode: "Markdown",
          reply_markup: {
            inline_keyboard: btns
          }
        };
```

where btns is

```
[
    [{ text: "Read first", url: "http://any", callback_data: "any_relevant_data }]
]
```

The button shows perfectly, the link works, but no callback is triggered and I never hit

```
bot.on('callback_query', (callback_message) => { //any action });
```

Is this a missing feature or it's me, doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [API Document](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton), you can't use `url` and `text` in the same time.

> This object represents one button of an inline keyboard.
>
> You must use exactly one of the optional fields.

Comment: Bingo. I knew I was missing something, and it's bold too...Thanks